# apache_request_headers() does not exist in php-fpm 5.4.38?

Tags: apache, php

All the documentation I can find says that `apache_request_headers()` should be available in PHP (even FastCGI) from version 5.4, but I do not have it (CentOS 6):

```
$ php-fpm -v
PHP 5.4.38 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Feb 18 2015 16:47:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

$ php -v
PHP 5.4.38 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2015 16:46:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 28 21:11:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ echo "<?php echo apache_request_headers();" | php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_request_headers() in - on line 1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation again... it appears you are running this from the command line.

5.5.7   This function became available in the CLI server.